# How to change image and db value?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to update db value when I click on an image,and also this image has to change. It works only when 'superata' is setted to 0 and so become 1, in the other case, only change the image,but not db value('superata' is a tinyint(1)). Why?

```
<?php

$risultato= mysql_query("select * from sfide where id='$id' ");
$ris=mysql_fetch_array($risultato);


if($ris[superata]==0)  {?>
    <img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="icons/switch_off.png">
<?} else  {?>
    <img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="icons/switch_on.png">
<?}?>

<script>
function changeImage() {
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
if (image.src.match("icons/switch_on")) {
  image.src = "icons/switch_off.png";
  <? mysql_query("UPDATE sfide SET superata='0' WHERE id='$id' ");?> 

} else {
    image.src = "icons/switch_on.png";
    <? mysql_query("UPDATE sfide SET superata='1' WHERE id='$id' ");?> 
}
```

}

Comment: You need a better understanding of separation between server execution (php) and client execution (javascript). In this particular case both your update queries are execute on server side before the pages is sent to the user and well before the user click on your images

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In which way can I execute the update only when the user click on the image?